# Error Starting MariaDB

Tags: mysql, startup, mariadb

I get the following error when starting MariaDB:

```
# systemctl status -l mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-06-03 10:44:56 UTC; 10min ago
  Process: 18624 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18624 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           ├─382 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
           └─538 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mariadb
/mariadb.log --pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: 2016-06-03 10:44:56 139898349344896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Can't open './ibdata1'
Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: 2016-06-03 10:44:56 139898349344896 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the sys
tem tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in
my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros
, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: 2016-06-03 10:44:56 139898349344896 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned e
rror.
Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: 2016-06-03 10:44:56 139898349344896 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAG
E ENGINE failed.
Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: 2016-06-03 10:44:56 139898349344896 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: 2016-06-03 10:44:56 139898349344896 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: Inno
DB
Jun 03 10:44:56 ms5l-hbpw.accessdomain.com mysqld[18624]: 2016-06-03 10:44:56 139898349344896 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I also looked at this journalctl - it had much the same information.

I am not familiar with 'InnoDB'. All that I understand is that I need to remove some things, but there is a warning not to remove the wrong thing. What do I do??

Comment: disk spaced checked?  binary-logs occupied your data disk?

Comment: Don't understand how to check this - data disk? binary-logs?

Comment: Maybe I have a version of MySQL that is conflicting with the MariaDB? How do I check this?

Comment: I mean, check your disk space. It maybe run out of disk space due to mysql binary logs filled up.

Comment: I think that is exactly the problem, but don't know how to solve this. I did a top review and saw that the biggest memory load was for MySQL. I did a systemctl and saw that mariadb could not load. How do I manage this memory problem?

Comment: I read about using a flush command after logging into MySQL to purge the binary logs, but I haven't even installed the mariadb program and don't know if an admin user and password has been created. What can be done apart from logging in o MySQL?

Comment: Please update your question and clarify your objective. Because you keep poping the word  Mysql and mix with mariadb. Their binary are NOT interchangeable.

Comment: MySQL CANNOT coexist with MariaDB in the same machine. They somewhat use the same library name but it is NOT shared.  Since VM is easy to setup, you should try install them into different VM.

Comment: I am trying to load MariaDB. This is what I see when I run a system check:

Comment: httpd.service                                            loaded active running   The Apache HTTP Server
  iptables.service                                         loaded active exited    IPv4 firewall with iptables
● mariadb.service                                          loaded failed failed    MariaDB database server
  mysql.service                                            loaded active running   LSB: start and stop MySQL
  network.service                                          loaded active exited    LSB: Bring up/down networking

Comment: I looked for binary files under /var/lib/MySQL - I did not see any.

Comment: When I run "systemctl stop mysqld" - it says the service is not loaded. Of course, the same for MariaDB gives the same result since this is the service that I am having trouble installing.

Comment: perhaps you should send a request to move your question to  http://dba.stackexchange.com/  . Perhaps explain your objective, you server OS and how you install Mariadb.  It seems lots of missing info need clarification.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the other exchange and found this thread which answered the problem. I know have MariaDB running and enabled.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61731/mariadb-mysql-server-does-not-start